# Merge 2 layers based on an attribute column in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a vector shapefile map that is divided into polygons. I want to add two columns to the attribute table with the Eastings/Northings coordinates of each polygon centroid.

So far what I've tried is:

menu > Vector > geom tools > polygon centroids

This gives me the centroids, but as a new layer. What I can't figure out how to do is to merge this layer with the original.

There is a command: menu > vector > join attribute by location.

But what I want is, I guess, 'join by attribute column' or something.

Comment: Is the only thing you want to add the lat and long columns?

Comment: @Nathan W, yes (though its not lat/lng but easting/northing). Found a solution in answer below though its a bit of a roundabout method. Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 7):

Ok, I think I just figured it out......

Layers Sidebar > Right mouse click on the layer containing the polygons > properties > Joins>

Add the layer you want to join up, and the columns name.

When its done, save as a new vector layer to get a layer with the attribute table merged.